# JTextField not appearing in GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I want to add a JTextField to the north region of a frame and a panel (which holds the copy of the same JTextField) to the east region.

But only the field in the north region appears. The panel in the east region is there but the problem is that the field isn't in the panel.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Gui {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        JTextField field = new JTextField("Your name");

        panel.add(field);
        frame.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, field);
        frame.add(BorderLayout.EAST, panel);

        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
       }
    }
```

Comment: you cannot set same jtextfield in 2 position but you can share same document  .you need to create new one.and why do u need to add same jtextfield to 2 positions what are u trying to do ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have two seperate `JTextField` objects if you want two seperate fields: try adding

```
JTextField field2 = new JTextField("Your second field");
```

and change the first `add()` call on your `frame` to

```
frame.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, field2);
```

This will produce

[image]

which I assume is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that Java is pass-by-value.

Comment: @lddangsta That's not entirely the problem, the problem is, a component can only reside within a single parent container, it's simply impossible to add a single instance of a component to more then one container at a time

Comment: Ok, but why does the field of the frame appear instead of the field of the panel?

Comment: Because you added it second.

Comment: The frame's field still appears after adding the panel first.

Comment: Yes because you add it to the panel first, then add the panel to the frame and then add the field to the frame.